# SharePoint 2010 - Bulk Upload List Data that contains Managed Metadata (Terms)

Tags: list, import, metadata, bulk

I have a list that contains a few columns of type Managed Metadata and want to upload a bunch of data (records) to the list. I understand that you can't do this within the Datasheet View of the list as the Managed Metadata fields are set to read only.

How can I achieve this? Out-Of-The-Box functionality? Custom Solution using Code? 3rd Party Tool? (if 3rd Party Tool, which ones could provide this functionality)

Any help on this would be much appreciated - we need to implement this functionality urgently.

Thanks in advance.

Grant.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no support for setting up metadata to multiple files at the time of uploading to SharePoint. However, you can use [SharePoint 2010 Batch Edit](http://sp2010batchedit.codeplex.com/) for bulk updating managed metadata using the SharePoint ribbon.

In SharePoint 2013, the datasheet view functionality can even edit/update managed metadata columns. The purpose is enable the metadata modification functionality available when editing an individual item to datasheet editing.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution using MS Access- SharePoint this might be useful for someone - http://sharepointlogics.com/2014/07/how-to-import-excel-spreadsheet-to.html

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)